# Is there any way to distinguish experimentally gauge mediation from gravity mediation in an unambiguous way?

Tags: particle-physics, supergravity, supersymmetry

There are lots of models of gravity-mediated SUSY breaking with various spectra as well as various general gauge mediation models. Are there any "smoking gun" experimental signatures that could distinguish between the two scenarios? Would this be possible to do at the LHC or would we need an ILC-type machine to do that?

Comment: They differ by the scale where SUSY is primarily broken, which is reflected in the gravitino mass etc. They have different predictions for the spectrum etc. I won't give you a full-fledged answer today but instead, let me recommend a brand new - today - lectures on SUSY from the top to down by Mike Dine: http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3386

Comment: Thank you @Luboš Motl ! I think I've found a good reference here: http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v76/i19/p3494_1

Comment: I just noticed this question. It's a good one without a clear answer. There are sum rules that arise in GMSB (but maybe in other scenarios too), and collider signatures that might most plausibly be interpreted as decays to gravitinos (but which can be faked by other models, even plausible ones). The two scenarios also tend to have fairly different cosmologies, although getting an experimental handle on the relevant things will be difficult. I might try to write a detailed answer at some point, but the short version is that it's an open question (one I've been thinking a lot about lately.)

Comment: The only *unambiguous* way is to detect the so-called messengers and to determine their properties.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the simplest "smoking gun" experimental distinction between [gravity- and gauge-mediation](https://online.kitp.ucsb.edu//online/spheno10/everett/) is that the former predicts that the [lightest supersymmetric particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightest_supersymmetric_particle) is a spin 1/2 [neutralino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutralino) while the latter predicts it is the spin 3/2 [gravitino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitino).
Although conceptually simple, this could be challenging experimentally, e.g. if the lifetime of the Next-to-Lightest Supersymmetric Particle (NLSP) that decays into a gravitino is so long that we never see it decay and can't be sure if it is the NLSP or LSP.

When this Physics SE question was asked many years ago,  the [Higgs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson) had not yet been discovered and it was plausible that SUSY might soon be discovered at the LHC and that there would eventually be sufficient LHC data on mass hierarchies, angular correlations, and other SUSY event characteristics to constrain how SUSY-breaking is mediated. We might still get lucky  and make the initial discovery of some new physics beyond the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) at the LHC, but it is very unlikely that the LHC could then provide enough data to pin down the details. A new machine such as an [International Linear Collider (ILC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Linear_Collider) or a [Future Circular Collider (FCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Circular_Collider) would be needed for that.